# PHP display today date and convert locale to italian

Tags: php, time, locale

I got a string that must to display today date and set locale to it-IT

```
$today= date("d m y"); 
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT.utf8"); 
print ucwords(strftime("%a %d %B %Y", strtotime($today)));
```

Got an error, the string is correctly translated to Italian, but print 01 Jan 1970 (01 Gennaio 1970 in italian) so i think got the UNIX timestamp 0.

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra step for no reason, simply use `print ucwords(strftime("%a %d %B %Y", time()));`

Comment: The extra step is cause i will call the $today other times in cutted part of my code.

Comment: So just use `$today = time()` and format that around in your code, why complicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$today= date("Y-m-d");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "it_IT.utf8");
echo ucwords(strftime("%a %d %B %Y", strtotime($today)));
```

your fomat `date('d m y')` can't be recognized by function `strtotime()`, it returns `false`